# Load custom template tag from another application?

Tags: django, django-templates

Is this possible in any way?
My project folder structure looks like this:

```
my_project:
    app1:
        templatetags:
            my_tags1.py (contains simple tags and inclusion tags)
    app2:
        templatetags:
            my_tags2.py (contains some simple tags)
    templates:
        app1: index.html
        app2: index.html
```

The ideas is to use a tag from my_tags1.py on the template app2/index.html. I simply tried:

```
{% load my_tags1 %}
```

but that gives me an error.

Comment: Yes it's possible - what have you tried? Show us your template code, and your directory layout (where do you define the template tags?).

Comment: Added some more information on question.

Comment: What error does it give you? (btw, the template code is missing a '%')

Comment: Edited the tag, added the '%'. I have it working now. The problem was that I had the same name for both tag files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the tag files have different names.