# loading custom tag filters from another app

Tags: django, django-templates, django-1.5, django-filter

I am really confused as to how could I load a custom tag filter from another app.
I have a similar problem like this [Load custom template tag from another application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404830/load-custom-template-tag-from-another-application)
And, I am doing it the same way, but still it doesnt load up and I am getting this error :

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
'fillme_tag' is not a valid tag library: Template library fillme_tag not found, tried django.templatetags.fillme_tag,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.fillme_tag,fillme.templatetags.fillme_tag
```

I have the app in settings installed app too.
I have tried loading it using various ways as mentioned below:
{% load fillme_tag %}
{% load fillme.fillme_tag %} #filleme is appname.

The structure is as follows:

```
my_project:
    app1:
        templates:
            index.html (this is where i want to load custom tag)
        views.py
        __init__.py
    fillme:
        templatetags:
            __init__.py
            fillme_tag.py (the tag lib)
        __init__.py
```

----- contents of fillme_tag.py ----

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='demotag')
def demotag(value):
    return value
```

Comment: Can you add content of fillme_tag.py?

Comment: just edited my question and added it :)

Comment: Yes, it is in INSTALLED_APPS in settings

Comment: In error message you copied we can see `fillme.templatetags.fillme_tag` so it tried to open it but failed as it can't find valid `Library` in `fillme.templatetags.fillme_tag`. Can you check if there is no typo in that file?

Comment: right, the file name had a typo, it was named as filleme_tag.py, instead of fillme_tag.py. Please edit your answer below and put this comment there, and I will tag it as a right answer! Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you missed `fillme/__init__.py`. Add it and this must work:

`{% load fillme_tag %}`

**UPDATE**

As error message said it couldn't open fillme_tag as it was invalid Library. My guess is you have a typo somewhere.